# Относительное положение

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-grid, wpf-canvas

Почему не правильно возвращается относительное положение?
Я хочу, чтобы button был на том же месте, как на grid, так и на canvas, ну в смысле я хотел бы, чтобы button стал как дочерним у canvas и был на том же месте и ниже я написал то, на чём я остановился. На картинке ниже видно, что после нажатия она слегка ушла влево, а мне нужно, чтобы она была на том же месте, как и до нажатия на button.

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="grd">
        <Canvas Name="cnvs" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="1276" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1550"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Height="63" Click="button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-side :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = button.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(cnvs) as UIElement));
    grd.Children.Remove(button);
    cnvs.Children.Add(button);
    Canvas.SetLeft(button, position.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(button, position.Y);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы привели два куска кода без каких либо объяснений, предлагаете нам самим догадаться, что Вы хотели получить и что у Вас не так?

Comment: @ixSci тему обновил

Comment: довольно стандартная беда, вы не учли поля и взаимное расположение грида и канваса, к сожалению я не настолько силен пока в WPF, так что готового рецепта дать не смогу, но при длительном отсутствии ответа, могу копнуть документацию.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, нужно сделать так:

```
    Point position = grd.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), cnvs);
```

**UPD**

да, @VladD прав, нужно вот так:

```
    Point position = button.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), cnvs);
```

Comment: А не `button.TranslatePoint` случайно?